# Value of array is changing with value of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

When I put an object into array using push method and then change the value of the object, the value of the object in the array also changes. How to prevent it?

```js
function onLoad() {
    let array = []
    let object = {}
    object[1] = [1,2]
    array.push(object)
    object[1] = [1,3]
    console.log(array)
}

onLoad();
```

I would like the code console [{1,2}] but it will console [{1,3}].

Would anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Objects in JavaScript are copied by reference. In order to duplicate them there are several methods, depending on the complexity of the object. In this case, using `assign` should fit. 
Use `array.push(Object.assign({}, object))` to add a cloned object to the array.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, Complex data types(Objects and arrays) are copied by reference whereas  primitive data types(Strings, Numbers, and Boolean) are copied by value

Simply put , Pass by reference will not create a copy instead refer to the same memory.
So original objects and arrays will be changed

Copy by value will create a copy of the value and hence original value will not be changed

```js
function change(array1){

array1[0] = "changed";

}

var original = ["original"]
change(original)

console.log(original)


function changePrimitive(input) {
  input = "changed"

}

var original = "original"


changePrimitive(original)


console.log(original);
```